# Expose resources behind a NAT

Tags: ip, nat

I have a very large storage pool located on a server behind a NAT.

Given that ipv6 is not possible in my case, what options do I have left to reach this pool?

If I rent a VPS with a public ip, could I use it to reach the machine? How?

Is there a way to avoid to use the bandwith of the VPS for data transfers?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is routing packet from your "public" server to the pool using `masquerading` or build a VPN where the server behind nat will connect to a server.

If so, your "private pool" will get a VPN IP, eg `10.0.1.0/24` and every peer of the VPN will be able to access each other.

Answer (score 1):

If the VPS with public IP is the same doing the NAT to the storage pool then yes, you can use NAT to access the storage pool from the public (valid) ip addreess.

You can also create a vpn from the public IP VPS to the server doing the NAT to the storage pool and serve content from there.

In any case, all content served by the public IP address will be accounted for, there's no way to avoid that (so directly answering your question about VPS badwdith usage: no, there's no way to not use the VPS bandwidth to do that).